# Vuetify - how to add margin to text within v-app-bar?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue3/Vuetify3, I'm trying to push the text of the v-app-bar about 300px to the right. When I just add a padding to the div element it doesn't do anything. Afaik vuetify works with flexbox, and I'm struggling to understand how to work with this.

Any explanations and/or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar>
      <v-container class="d-flex align-center py-0">
        <v-app-bar-title class="pl-0">
          <div class="d-flex align-center">
            <v-avatar
              rounded="0"
              class="mr-3"
              image="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/docs/images/logos/v.png"
            />

            Example Sentence that should be centered
          </div>
        </v-app-bar-title>
      </v-container>
    </v-app-bar>
```

Comment: did you try <v-app-bar style="margin-left: 300px;"> ?

Comment: @emi that shifts the whole appbar to the right, not just the text. I'm also trying to keep it responsive so I don't want it hard coded like that to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I came up with this, it is also responsive. This should just move the text:

```
<style>
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    .app-bar-text {
      margin-left: 300px;
    }
  }
</style>

<v-app-bar>
  <v-container class="d-flex align-center py-0">
    <v-app-bar-title class="pl-0">
      <div class="app-bar-text">
        Example Sentence that should be centered
      </div>
    </v-app-bar-title>
  </v-container>
</v-app-bar>
```